# Bash. Insert a function call in call stack

Tags: bash, plugins, hook, callstack

I'm trying to create "some kind of function hooking system" for a bash script. The main bash script already exists and the point is to be able to create some kind of plugins system in order to let the users to create little bash scripts containing their own stuff under these three methods:

- Prehooking -> users will be able to create a function that will be executed before the function of the main script which they choose
- Overriding -> users will be able to override completely a function of the main script in order to rewrite it with custom content
- Posthooking -> users will be able to create a function that will be executed immediately after a function of the main script which they choose

I have already working the plugins system for prehooking and overriding functions. The main script parses the little plugins scripts and following some rules and validations (nomenclature etc...) if the plugin is well done it works.

My problem is trying to create the posthooking feature and I'm looking for ideas. The reason is because for prehooking, I rewrite the entire function doing a sed over its content and searching the first `{` appearance to be replaced by `{ call_to_prehook` and it works like a charm. But I can't do the same for posthooking. I can't replace the last appearance of the `}` to set something like `call_to_posthook }` because if the function has a return it will not work. That posthook will never be reached.

Now I'm struggling about if it could be possible to "inject" a function call in the call stack or something like that. Not sure if in bash the "tree of calls" can be checked even before of reaching it.

A little PoC for better understanding:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Main script

function main() {
    magic_function
    one
    two
}

function one() {
    echo "one"
}

function two() {
    echo "two"
}

function magic_function() {
    echo "this function parses plugins and execute needed stuff to modify functions"
    echo "I hope to find some way here to do possible the posthooking"
}
```

```
#!/bin/bash
#Plugin done by somebody

function posthook_one() {
    echo "stuff to be executed after function one of the main script"
}
```

I guess that to perform a posthooking of function one it could be done performing a prehooking of function two, but that is not a valid idea for me due the complexity of the real script and of course because in that way, last function couldn't be posthooked.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: *"inject" a function call in the call stack or something like that.* Not possible afaik. *I rewrite the entire function doing a sed over its content and searching the first { appearance to be replaced by { call_to_prehook and it works like a charm.* Not a good idea at all

Comment: `bash` doesn't really contain the kinds of introspection mechanisms that would be needed for this. Trying to parse bash scripts with `sed` is hopeless unless you require the programmers to follow a strict formatting style.

Comment: Rather than parse the function, you should just rename `one` to `original_one`, then redefine `one` to execute `prehook_one; original_one "$@"; posthook_one`. That's how this type of thing is usually done in other languages.

Comment: Alternatively, insist that your posthook function takes the return code as input and returns the return code. Then you could replace any `return whatever` with `return MyPostHook whatever` Though I prefer @Barmar's idea, you could still incorporate this mechanism to make your prehook and posthook change behaviour.

Comment: Take a look at how the "advice" mechanism works in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: omg @Barmar, that's the kind of idea I was looking for. Put it as answer and I'll accept it (I'm referring to you second comment). Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what to put in an answer. I don't know how to automate renaming the function in your `magic_function`.

Comment: Don't worry, I was not looking for anybody to do my code... just looking for ideas. Put the same as in comment, is enough for me.